# MySQL Issues Creating Trigger - Need SUPER privilege?

Tags: sql, mysql

I am trying to create a trigger that basically says, if any cell in the store_coupon table changes, it copies and pastes that old and new detail into the coupon_mods table, functioning basically to give me a historical log of changes that have occurred on the store_coupon table and when. Below is the code. When I run it, it says I need the SUPER privilege. Not sure why this is such a risky trigger to need SUPER privilege. Why, and is there a way to get around this? Am I writing something wrong here?

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_coupon_mods
AFTER UPDATE ON store_coupon
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
        IF NEW.description <> OLD.description THEN
        INSERT INTO store_coupon_mods (mod_date, r_no, mod_col, mod_changefrom, mod_changeto)
        VALUES (CURDATE(), OLD.r_no, 'description', OLD.description, NEW.description); END IF;

        IF NEW.event_type <> OLD.event_type THEN
        INSERT INTO store_coupon_mods (mod_date, r_no, mod_col, mod_changefrom, mod_changeto)
        VALUES (CURDATE(), OLD.r_no, 'event_type', OLD.event_type, NEW.event_type); END IF;

        IF NEW.store_no <> OLD.store_no THEN
        INSERT INTO store_coupon_mods (mod_date, r_no, mod_col, mod_changefrom, mod_changeto)
        VALUES (CURDATE(), OLD.r_no, 'store_no', OLD.store_no, NEW.store_no); END IF;

        IF NEW.total_upc <> OLD.total_upc THEN
        INSERT INTO store_coupon_mods (mod_date, r_no, mod_col, mod_changefrom, mod_changeto)
        VALUES (CURDATE(), OLD.r_no, 'total_upc', OLD.total_upc, NEW.total_upc); END IF;

        IF NEW.upc_list <> OLD.upc_list THEN
        INSERT INTO store_coupon_mods (mod_date, r_no, mod_col, mod_changefrom, mod_changeto)
        VALUES (CURDATE(), OLD.r_no, 'upc_list', OLD.upc_list, NEW.upc_list); END IF;

        IF NEW.start <> OLD.start THEN
        INSERT INTO store_coupon_mods (mod_date, r_no, mod_col, mod_changefrom, mod_changeto)
        VALUES (CURDATE(), OLD.r_no, 'start', OLD.start, NEW.start); END IF;

        IF NEW.end <> OLD.end THEN
        INSERT INTO store_coupon_mods (mod_date, r_no, mod_col, mod_changefrom, mod_changeto)
        VALUES (CURDATE(), OLD.r_no, 'end', OLD.end, NEW.end); END IF;

        IF NEW.discount_amt <> OLD.discount_amt THEN
        INSERT INTO store_coupon_mods (mod_date, r_no, mod_col, mod_changefrom, mod_changeto)
        VALUES (CURDATE(), OLD.r_no, 'discount_amt', OLD.discount_amt, NEW.discount_amt); END IF;

        IF NEW.comments <> OLD.comments THEN
        INSERT INTO store_coupon_mods (mod_date, r_no, mod_col, mod_changefrom, mod_changeto)
        VALUES (CURDATE(), OLD.r_no, 'comments', OLD.comments, NEW.comments); END IF;

        IF NEW.r_origin <> OLD.r_origin THEN
        INSERT INTO store_coupon_mods (mod_date, r_no, mod_col, mod_changefrom, mod_changeto)
        VALUES (CURDATE(), OLD.r_no, 'r_origin', OLD.r_origin, NEW.r_origin); END IF;
        
        END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: `CREATE TRIGGER` is its own permission in MySql. Your account needs that permission.

Comment: but you might be running into this bug
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=39489

Comment: Bill - I'm not seeing the difference between your code and mine. What did you change? Also Garr - I already have the CREATE TRIGGER permission. I also tried disabling the binary log and still get the same SUPER privilege error block.